# Why always my last e2e test on order fails in playwright?

Tags: node.js, testing, e2e-testing, playwright

After long running my test , i saw that my last test on order always flaky and when my flacky test run second time it pass. I was thinking my test are not written correctly, but when I change the order always the last one become flacky. I want to share some of my code

```js
test.describe.only('Collab Room documents page file options', () => {
  const auth0ManagementClient = new Auth0ManagementClient();
  let users!: { Admin: Auth0User; Member: Auth0User };
  let page: Page;
  let loginPage: LoginPage;
  let basePage: BasePage;
  let documentsPage: DocumentsPage;
  let filePage: FilePage;
  let toastify: Toastify;
  let documentSetup: DocumentSetup;
  let projectsPage: ProjectsPage;
  let dndkit: Dndkit;
  let organisation: Organisation;

  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    const Admin = await auth0ManagementClient.getOrCreateUserWithProfile(
      'collab-room-superuser'
    );
    const Member = await auth0ManagementClient.getOrCreateUserWithProfile(
      'collab-room-user'
    );
    users = { Admin, Member };

    organisation = await createOrganisation();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    basePage = new BasePage(page, organisation.slug);
    loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
    documentsPage = new DocumentsPage(page);
    filePage = new FilePage(page);
    toastify = new Toastify(page);
    documentSetup = new DocumentSetup(page, organisation.slug);
    await documentSetup.beforeAll({
      projectName: 'e2e-documents-list-file-options',
      adminUser: users.Admin,
      memberUser: users.Member,
      files: ['Steiner_RGB.jpg', 'Test_abc.docx'],
    });
  });

  test.afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
    await cleanUpBoxCache(organisation.slug, getTrackedProjectIds());
    await deleteOrganisation(organisation.slug);
  });

  test.describe('as project admin', () => {
    test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
      const context = await browser.newContext();
      page = await context.newPage();
      basePage = new BasePage(page, organisation.slug);
      loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
      documentsPage = new DocumentsPage(page);
      filePage = new FilePage(page);
      toastify = new Toastify(page);
      projectsPage = new ProjectsPage(page, organisation.slug);
      dndkit = new Dndkit(page);

      await basePage.goto();
      await loginPage.login(users.Admin.email, users.Admin.password);
      await basePage.closeCookieBanner();
      await projectsPage
        .getMyProject('e2e-documents-list-file-options')
        .click();
      await expect(page.getByTestId('project-summary')).toBeVisible();
    });

    test.beforeEach(async () => {
      await basePage.gotoDocuments();
      await expect(documentsPage.getFileListTable()).toBeVisible({
        timeout: 45000,
      });
      await documentsPage.expectBreadcrumb('All files');
      await documentsPage.openFolder('E2ETest1');
      await documentsPage.expectBreadcrumb('All files', 'E2ETest1');
    });

    test.afterEach(async () => {
      await documentSetup.afterEach({ reload: true, page });
    });

    test('should be able to upload new version', async () => {
      const folderRow = documentsPage.getFileListItemByName('Steiner_RGB.jpg');
      await expect(
        folderRow.getByTestId('file-list-version-label')
      ).toBeHidden();

      await documentsPage.openFileListItemOptions(folderRow);

      await filePage.uploadFile(['Steiner_RGB.jpg'], async () => {
        await documentsPage.getOptionsUploadNewVersionButton().click();
      });

      await filePage.expectUploadAndCloseOverlay([
        { name: 'Steiner_RGB.jpg', status: 'success' },
      ]);

      await expect(page.getByTestId('file-list-version-label')).toBeVisible();
      const updatedFolderRow =
        documentsPage.getFileListItemByName('Steiner_RGB.jpg');
      await expect(
        updatedFolderRow.getByTestId('file-list-version-label')
      ).toBeVisible({ timeout: 30000 });
      await expect(
        updatedFolderRow.getByTestId('file-list-version-label')
      ).toContainText('V2');

      await documentSetup.recreateFile('Steiner_RGB.jpg');
    });
  });

  test.describe('as project member', () => {
    test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
      const context = await browser.newContext();
      page = await context.newPage();
      basePage = new BasePage(page, organisation.slug);
      loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
      documentsPage = new DocumentsPage(page);
      filePage = new FilePage(page);
      projectsPage = new ProjectsPage(page, organisation.slug);
      toastify = new Toastify(page);
      dndkit = new Dndkit(page);

      await basePage.goto();
      await loginPage.login(users.Member.email, users.Member.password);
      await basePage.closeCookieBanner();
      await projectsPage
        .getMyProject('e2e-documents-list-file-options')
        .click();
      await expect(page.getByTestId('project-summary')).toBeVisible();
    });

    test.beforeEach(async () => {
      await basePage.gotoDocuments();
      await expect(documentsPage.getFileListTable()).toBeVisible({
        timeout: 45000,
      });
      await documentsPage.expectBreadcrumb('All files');
      await documentsPage.openFolder('E2ETest1');
      await documentsPage.expectBreadcrumb('All files', 'E2ETest1');
    });

    test.afterEach(async () => {
      await documentSetup.afterEach({ reload: true, page });
    });

    test('should not be able to upload new version with a different name', async () => {
      const folderRow = documentsPage.getFileListItemByName('Steiner_RGB.jpg');
      await expect(
        folderRow.getByTestId('file-list-version-label')
      ).toBeHidden();

      await documentsPage.openFileListItemOptions(folderRow);

      await filePage.uploadFile(['Test_xyz.pdf'], async () => {
        await documentsPage.getOptionsUploadNewVersionButton().click();
      });

      await filePage.expectUploadAndCloseOverlay([
        { name: 'Test_xyz.pdf', status: 'success' },
      ]);

      const updatedFolderRow =
        documentsPage.getFileListItemByName('Steiner_RGB.jpg');
      await expect(
        updatedFolderRow.getByTestId('file-list-version-label')
      ).toBeHidden();
    });

    test('should not be able to rename file or delete file', async () => {
      const folderRow = documentsPage.getFileListItemByName('Steiner_RGB.jpg');
      await documentsPage.openFileListItemOptions(folderRow);
      await expect(documentsPage.getOptionsRenameButton()).toBeHidden();
      await expect(documentsPage.getOptionsDeleteButton()).toBeHidden();
    });
  });
});
```

In this case my test **should not be able to rename file or delete file** will be flacky and it will fail in first run. But if I change the order and make **should not be able to upload new version with a different name** will be flacky one. Then I though maybe i am mistaken on beforeEach usage with **browser context** and used **  await context.close();
** before each test. But it did not worked
[image]

Comment: Can you share an minimal reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example